# connection to the database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

im trying to learn `PDO`

i've made this code to connect to the database

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "testcreate";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "mysql";

    if (!$db) {
        throw new Exception('failed to connect to mysql')
    }

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8', ''.$dbuser.'', ''.$dbpass.'');

    } catch (MyFunkyException $e) {
        echo "Caught exception : ", $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

the connection works, but when i try to make an error and i want to catch the error

this error popup

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'failed to connect to mysql' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\test.php on line 8
```

can you help me fix the error or shows me the right way to do it

Comment: It's `PDO` not `POD` - updated question :)

Comment: Why do you concatenate `''` with `$dbuser` and `$dbpass`?

Comment: You're checking if `$db` is set _before_ you try to connect!

Comment: Is nobody going to bother explaining exceptions, or why the real problem here is `MyFunkyException`?

Comment: What's wrong with the error you are getting currently?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try by using this code below

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "testcreate";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "mysql";

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8', $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you , that worked with me but i had to change `$dbh->setAttribute` to `$db->setAttribute`

Comment: Can you explain what you changed, and why?

Comment: @jcsanyi i removed     `if (!$db) {`
        `throw new Exception('failed to connect to mysql')`
    `}` because is useless and i add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: None of that actually fixed anything. You also changed MyFunkyException to PDOException - which was the real problem

Comment: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` also useless for this case.

Comment: especially since you do it after the code that throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that

1. You're trying to throw exception before connection and outside of try.
2. There is no need to throw your own exception because PDO [throws its own exception if connection fails](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-errors).
3. Also you'd consider [exception type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17460222/1503018).

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8', ''.$dbuser.'', ''.$dbpass.'');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Caught exception : ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also, there is no need to turn PDO on exceptions to catch an exception. But if you are trying [to handle errors with exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) you must turn on that feature right after connection is established.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense, i agree. What i have to put inside of the catch in this example?

Comment: Nothing. No try catch should be here at all. PHP will handle it better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you **don't** want to catch anything.
At least until you want it only to echo the error message out.

Also, exceptions has nothing to do with PDO syntax.

Answer (score -1):

The real problem here is in this line:

```
} catch (MyFunkyException $e) {
```

`MyFunkyException` is a classname of the type of exception you want to catch.
PDO doesn't throw a `MyFunkyException` exception - [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) state that it throws a `PDOException` exception.

You can fix this by changing the line like this:

```
} catch (PDOException $e) {
```

Or by catching *all exceptions* regardless of type, like this:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
```